# How to untar a directory of tar files having tar.gz files internally in it?

Tags: python, linux, shell, tar, gzip

I have a directory of `.tar` files and in each tar file there is a `.tar.gz` file in it. How to extract the TAR files and `.tgz` files with a single command?

Comment: you untar then list the directory and if any file is still tar you call the same function? should be quite easy with recursion

Comment: Please add code to show what you have tried.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this Q belongs on the unix.stackexchange.com site.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with a `for` loop in Bash.

```
$ for i in *.tar; do tar xvf "$i"; done
$ for j in *.tar.gz; do tar zxvf "$j"; done
```